# Read all the lines between a pattern match using Perl

Tags: regex, loops, perl

I want to read a csv file. The csv files is like below,

```
cat,dog,0
apple,banana,0
#start_loop
jug,ball,0
tub, jar,3
#stop_loop
phone,bottle,10
#per head
#start_loop
cup,book,7
laptop,charger,9
#stop_loop
```

For above csv, I want to read between the #start and #stop. Also, I want to differentiate two #start_loop 's for ex, the lines from first #start_loop goes to one array and another #start_loop goes to another array.

The expected result would be:

```
@array1 = {jug ball 0, tub jar 3}
```

and

```
@array2 = { cup book 7, laptop charger 9}
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the flip-flop operator. It's value will be 1 for the #start line and will contain E for the #stop line.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @arr;

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my $inside = /^#start_loop/ .. /^#stop_loop/;
    if ($inside) {
        push @arr, [] if 1 == $inside;
        undef $inside if 1 == $inside
                      || $inside =~ /E/;
        push @{ $arr[-1] }, $_ if $inside;
    }
}

use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@arr;
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplified version of choroba's solution:

```
my @arr;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my $inside = /^#start_loop/ .. /^#stop_loop/;
    if    ( $inside == 1   ) { push @arr, [];          }  # Start line
    elsif ( $inside !~ /E/ ) { push @{ $arr[-1] }, $_; }  # Middle line
}
```

Without the flip-flop:

```
my @arr;
my $inside;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    if    ( /^#start_loop/ ) { $inside = 1; push @arr, []; }  # Start line
    elsif ( /^#stop_loop/  ) { $inside = 0;                }  # Stop line
    elsif ( $inside        ) { push @{ $arr[-1] }, $_;     }  # Middle line
}
```